# Swift Combine sink value is different from value of @Published property

Tags: swift, combine

I'm running into an issue where in Combine where I have a boolean @Published property.

When I set it to true,
the sink closure is run and I can look at the value being received. It's true. But when I compare it against the actual property that I am observing, they are different.

This bit of code can be simply run in a playground. I'm not sure how this works or why the values would be different

```
class TestModel {
    @Published var isLoading = false
}

let model = TestModel()

model.$isLoading.sink { (isLoading) in
    if isLoading != model.isLoading {
        print("values NOT same")
    }
}

model.isLoading = true
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`@Published` publishes the new value before it actually modifies the stored value. [This is documented:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published)

> When the property changes, publishing occurs in the property’s willSet block, meaning subscribers receive the new value before it’s actually set on the property.

If the `@Published` property is part of an `ObservableObject`, it also triggers the enclosing object's `objectWillChange` publisher before the new value is actually set on the property.

(This answer used to include a disassembly of part of the `@Published` wrapper, but that is no longer needed because Apple has now documented the behavior.)

Comment: Brilliant stuff. — I wonder if this has something to do with the change from ObservableObject `objectDidChange` to `objectWillChange`.

Comment: Could be. This method is also responsible for posting that notification at address `46251` by calling `Combine.ObservableObjectPublisher.send() -> ()`.

Comment: This is by design: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published   "When the property changes, publishing occurs in the property’s **willSet** block, meaning subscribers receive the new value before it’s actually set on the property."

Comment: is it possible to subscribe to changes at the `didSet` stage?

Comment: @lewis Not with an `@Published` property.